# How to save an Uploded ImageView in javafx

Tags: javafx, imageview, saving-data

I am working on a JavaFX project(application), i have all my methods setup adn it all works include a Customer Upload Image method (he can upload his photo), I have also a Serializable File that include all my app information but it does not allow me to save the image that "the customer upload" .
i am searching for a way that allow me to save this photo after i change scenses or exit the project

here is my Serialization code :

```
public static void saveFile() {
    System.out.println("Saving");

    // Serialization
    try {
        // Saving of object in a file
        FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("Rest.ser");
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(file);

        out.writeObject(restaurant);

        out.close();
        file.close();

    }

    catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}

public static boolean readingFile() {

    try {
        File filec = new File("Rest.ser");
        if (filec.isFile() == false || filec.canRead() == false)
            return false;
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(filec);
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(file);

        restaurant = (Restaurant) in.readObject();
        
        in.close();
        file.close();

        System.out.println("Object has been deserialized ");
        return true;
    }

    catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("No ser file");
    }

    catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException is caught");
    }
    return false;
}
```

and here is my photo upload code:

```
@FXML
private void UploadImageActionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
   
    //Set extension filter
    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterJPG
            = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("JPG files (*.JPG)", "*.JPG");
    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterjpg
            = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("jpg files (*.jpg)", "*.jpg");
    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterPNG
            = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("PNG files (*.PNG)", "*.PNG");
    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterpng
            = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("png files (*.png)", "*.png");
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters()
            .addAll(extFilterJPG, extFilterjpg, extFilterPNG, extFilterpng);
    //Show open file dialog
    File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

    try {
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(file);
       WritableImage image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufferedImage, null);
        Customerimage.setImage(image);
        Customerimage.setFitWidth(200);
        Customerimage.setFitHeight(200);
        Customerimage.scaleXProperty();
        Customerimage.scaleYProperty();
        Customerimage.setSmooth(true);
        Customerimage.setCache(true);
    
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        

        for (int readNum; (readNum = fin.read(buf)) != -1;) {
            bos.write(buf, 0, readNum);
        }
        byte[] person_image = bos.toByteArray();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger("ss");
    }

    
 }
```

ant one can help me please:)
thank you.

Comment: "Upload" in what sense? If your application is completely local and you're essentially just linking a photo, then simply store the path (or copy the image to an application-specific location, then store _that_ path); load the image from the stored path (if the file is missing, alert the user). If your application is an interface for some remote application, send the image to the server and have the server store it however is appropriate; send the image by copying the file (that way you send the compressed version rather than the raw, uncompressed pixel data).

Comment: The scence that i want to upload the image to is called @FXML screen , i think i undatood what you said but i cant think of a way or a code that can help me store the image Path. I am new to javaFX and i am still learning :\

Comment: You can load an [image directly from a URL](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)), which is a string path to the location.  Similarly for [ImageView](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)).  You can construct this location from the file chosen by the user in the `FileChooser`.  You may not need all of the code you have to load and save image data.  If you wished to remember the image location you could just store it somewhere as a string.

Comment: Unrelated, but for serialization, in many cases, I would recommend the use of [Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial) to serialize to JSON or XML,  rather than the Java native object serializer.  That would be for meta-data, such as the file location.  If you needed to save the actual image data, then storage to a standard format such as PNG or JPEG would be preferred.  The two approaches can be used in combination (meta-data in JSON and stored image bits in a compressed image format).

Comment: If all you need to accomplish is copying the existing image file to a new image file location, you can do that using a single line [`Files.copy(source, target, options)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...)).

Answer (score 0):

You can load an image directly from a URL, which is a string path to the location. Similarly for ImageView. You can construct this location from the file chosen by the user in the FileChooser. You may not need all of the code you have to load and save image data. If you wished to remember the image location you could just store it somewhere as a string.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.